# Issue occurring while using this.state in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have one file name 'FirstContainer.js' , code for that file goes as

```
getInitialState: function(){
return{
  currentX: null,
}
}
```

in currentX value Im saving x-coOrdinate of current view.

Now I have different file 'DraggableView.js', in which Im using some PanResponders and returning value of release coordinates and capturing them into 'FirstContainer.js' as that is my parent file.

So render function of FirstContainer will look like

```
render: function(){
//some more code goes here
<DraggableView ...
// by next line Im getting panResponder release values
releaseValues={(e, gesture) => {
    //Now here is the problem , I need to use this.state.currentX here       , but unfortunately I cant as 'this' will refer to DraggableView
Any suggestion how can I achieve that ? 
}}/>
//some more lines of code
}
```

Adding screenshot for reference :

[image]

Comment: That is incorrect. `this` refers to the containing component. That is the benefit of using the arrow function syntax.

Comment: So what you want to say ? I can use this.state.currentX here ? Bcoz its causing problem and throwing error cant find currentX of undefined. @azium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top of your render function before you return the "ui-code" itself.
Define a variable:

```
`var _this = this`.
```

It would look something like this:

```
render: function(){
var _this = this;
//some more code goes here
<DraggableView ...
releaseValues={(e, gesture) => {
// use _this here
}}/>
//some more lines of code
}`
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a ton !